# QTableView with different column width

Tags: c++, qt, size, qtableview, qabstracttablemodel

I have a `QTableView` width `QAbstractTableModel` in the application and i want to make each column a different width, with resizing option `ui->tableView->horizontalHeader()->setSectionResizeMode (QHeaderView::Stretch);`

In my model i do:

```cpp
    class rangeModel : public QAbstractTableModel {
    //other code ....... 

    QVariant rangeModel::headerData(int section, Qt::Orientation orientation, int role) const
    {
        if (orientation != Qt::Horizontal) 
            return QVariant();
        if (role != Qt::DisplayRole && role != Qt::SizeHintRole) 
            return QVariant();
        if(role == Qt::SizeHintRole) 
        {
           switch (section) {
              case 0: return QSize(58, 20);
              case 1: return QSize(58, 20);
              case 2: return QSize(58, 20);
              case 3: return QSize(228, 20);
           }
        }
        switch (section) {
            case 0: return "PREFIXMIN";
            case 1: return "PREFIXMAX";
            case 2: return "VALUE";
            case 3: return "PROGRESS BAR";
            default: return QVariant();
        }
    }
```

So i want my rows to be different in size, but it doesn't happen, the view ignores `QSizeHint` for some reason, and also it doesn't work even without `QHeaderView::Stretch` option. How to make the columns and headers different in sizes?

Comment: I doubt that, you can do that with QTableView but you can write your own view for that. You can write your own view by inheriting qabstractitemview

Comment: @sanjay so i need to inherit qabstractitemview and reimplement `QAbstractItemView::sizeHintForColumn(int column) const` and return the size i want? Or that would not be enough, and i will need to reimplement `resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *event)` ?

Answer (score 2):

You might want to use this:

```
 ui->tableView->resizeColumnsToContents();//resize all the columns based on longest data in every column.
```

But if you really did meant to resize them exactly with the width values you used on your code:

```
ui->tableView->horizontalHeader()->setSectionResizeMode (QHeaderView::Stretch);
ui->tableView->setColumnWidth(0,58);
ui->tableView->setColumnWidth(1,58);
ui->tableView->setColumnWidth(2,58);
ui->tableView->setColumnWidth(3,228);
```

Comment: Could you explain how your answer addresses the problem(s) from the question? Code-only answers are not very useful, especially for further readers that stumble upon this post. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry. I was assuming that , that single line of code is self explanatory. But another mistake I did is, I assumed that he just calculated himself the width he needs to fit all the data in the columns that's why I recommended using `resizeColumnsToContents()`. Anyways, i edited my answer now and included the `setColumnWidth()` incase he really does want to set those specific widths. Which I never expected that he never tried the `setColumnWidth()` function.

Comment: Unfortunately, setting the column width will only work if your number of columns is known beforehand. The resizeColumnsToContents() function is very slow.  If columns can be added dynamically (which is one of the main purposes of QAbstractTableModel), then you must subclass QTableView or find another alternative.